# Sync MySQL 4.0 table to MySQL 5.6 server every few minutes

Tags: mysql, replication, mysqldump

I am tasked with getting a copy of a table on a MySQL 4.0 server synced to a completely different database on a MySQL 5.6 server every few minutes for the purposes of having that table available during a migration phase for a really old application.  Basically this:

```
10.10.10.10:oldb.table -> 20.20.20.20:newdb.table
```

The table is ~65,000 rows and ~18MB.

Obviously I cannot use replication with version 4.0.  I have looked at using mysqlhotcopy, but it appears that it only copies entire databases, and I need the table to live in a different database on the destination host.  I have also looked at using mysqldump, however I cannot have the table on the new server be dropped for the new data to be inserted resulting in queries that see an empty table, and if I use --insert-ignore --no-create-db --no-create-info it still does not account for deleted rows on the source table.  I also looked at selecting all rows from the existing table and doing a REPLACE INTO, or INSERT/UPDATE ON DUPLICATE KEY but this would also not account for rows that were deleted from the source table.  Any thoughts on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://www.mpopp.net/2006/11/running-stored-procedures-on-mysql-4-x/) looks interesting and might (just might) be a solution to your issue. It shows how a 4.1 server can simulate Stored Procedures (SPs - not available till version 5 of the MySQL server) using the Federated storage engine. Basically, it shows that a 5.x server can access data on a 4.x server and even update that data. It also shows that you can use 5.x to read the data also. This is probably a good fit for your requirements, however the federated engine does not support transactions. It's also covered [here](http://www.tocker.ca/2013/10/17/how-do-you-use-the-federated-storage-engine.html) (Morgan Tocker is a MySQL community manager).

Comment: Ah yes, federated tables!  This is exactly what I needed!  Could you please edit your answer to include some details about the solution posted in the link and I will give you credit for answering?